GeoServer monitoring extension hibernate option does not work
I have a GeoServer installation (2.25.1).
I've installed the monitor extension. I want to export the requests data to a PostgreSQL RDBMS.
I have set monitor.properties storage to hibernate.
I've created a db.properties file :
driver=org.postgresql.Driver
url=jdbc:postgresql://:ip:port/db_name
username=
password=
No matter what I do I get this in the geoserver.log:
WARN   [geoserver.monitor] - monitoring storage hibernate not found, falling back to 'memory'
In the documentation I see that the default setting for hibernate is having an H2 db in the folder "monitoring" I don't see that either.
In my investigation I circle back each time to some community extension called "Hibernate Monitor Extension" which I can't seem to find anywhere.
What is wrong here?

It looks like the hibernate monitor plugin is no longer built by default, this may be by design as it wasn't working or building, or it could be an accident. I'd say talk to the maintainer but as it is a community module it probably doesn't have any one looking after it so there is an opportunity for you to step in.

@IanTurton First of all thank you for your answer. I came across this https://github.com/DLR-TS/GeoServer-Monitor-PostgreSQL which I unfortunately have not been able to install. I think currently and given some time pressure and not being too with Java  I'll write a Python script that will parse audit logs and write to a Postgres.
